# ignorar tipo de dato diferente en Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class MessageRS {
        private String errorCode;
        private String description;
        private DATA DATA;

        public MessageRS() {
        }

        public MessageRS(String errorCode, String description, DATA DATA) {
            super();
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
            this.description = description;
            this.DATA = DATA;
        }

        @JsonProperty("errorCode")
        public String getErrorCode() {
            return errorCode;
        }

        public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
        }

        @JsonProperty("description")
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }


        public static class DATA {
            private String EMAIL;


            public DATA() {

            }

            public DATA(String eMAIL) {
                super();
                EMAIL = eMAIL;
            }

            @JsonProperty("EMAIL")
            public String getEMAIL() {
                return EMAIL;
            }

            public void setEMAIL(String eMAIL) {
                EMAIL = eMAIL;
            }       

        }
```

Actualmente necesitaria que al venir el DATA con otro tipo pueda ignorarlo o evadir que la deserialización no se parta por el tipo de dato ya que es dinamico y si viene con el formato bien pueda obtenerlo , pero si viene con un formato que no es el que definio lo ignore , Existe algun propiedad Jackson para esto ? Gracias

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of jsonMapperMM.response.LoginRS$MessageRS$DATA: no
>   String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String
>   value ('')  at [Source:
>   {"headerRS":{"orgMsgId":"msgId","orgChannelRef":"ChannelReference","orgChannelId":"","orgTransactionType":"xxxx","timestamp":"2018-07-17T12:49:10-05:00","errorCode":"0","errorDesc":""},"messageRS":{"errorCode":"-30150","description":"-680","DATA":""}};
>   line: 1, column: 351] (through reference chain:
>   jsonMapperMM.response.LoginRS["messageRS"]->jsonMapperMM.response.LoginRS$MessageRS["DATA"])

Comment: Podrías definir un deserializador personalizado para tratar ese JSON en lugar del que usa Jackson por defecto. Aquí tienes un ejemplo: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization